# WordPress admin filters not working properly on multiple filtering (only read last filter)

Tags: wordpress, filter, filtering, wordpress-hook, wordpress-admin

I had create a custom post-type called 'cliente_finale'.

I've some custom field on it and everything works fine.

I've a trouble with custom filtering 'in edit.php'.

I'had create 2 custom filters, and they works fine if used singularly or in addition with every other default WordPress filter. But when they are used togheter, I can see only the last filter results (ordered with the hook priority).

I think that my query results are in some way overrided by the 'last' (in priority) filter.

I'm not figuring out the solution, probably for a lack in the WordPress core functionalities.

Here the code for this filters...

```
/* =======================================
FILTRO COMM. PRINCIPALE
======================================= */

function list_filter_principale_cliente_finale(){
  $type = 'cliente_finale';
  if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
    $type = $_GET['post_type'];
  }



  //only add filter to post type you want
  if ('cliente_finale' == $type){
    //change this to the list of values you want to show
    //in 'label' => 'value' format

    global $wpdb;
    $all_commerciali = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'cliente-finale-commerciale-principale-commerciale_principale_commerciale_principale' " );
    $values = array();
    foreach($all_commerciali as $principale){
      $principaleID = $principale->meta_value;
      $principaleNome = get_user_meta($principaleID,'nickname',true);
      if(!in_array($principaleID, $values)){
        $values[$principaleNome] = $principaleID;
      }

    }
    ksort($values);

    ?>
    <select name="principale">
      <option value=""><?php _e('Tutti i principali ', 'wose45436'); ?></option>
      <?php
      $current_v = isset($_GET['principale'])? $_GET['principale']:'';
      foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
        printf
        (
          '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
          $value,
          $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
          $label
        );
      }
      ?>
    </select>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'list_filter_principale_cliente_finale' );


/**
* if submitted filter by post meta
*
* make sure to change META_KEY to the actual meta key
* and POST_TYPE to the name of your custom post type

*/
function filtra_principale_cliente_finale( $vars ){
  global $pagenow;
  $type = 'cliente_finale';
  if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
    $type = $_GET['post_type'];
  }

  if(!is_administrator()){
    $_GET['principale'] = get_current_user_id();
  }

  if ( 'cliente_finale' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['principale']) && $_GET['principale'] != '') {
    $vars['meta_key'] = 'cliente-finale-commerciale-principale-commerciale_principale_commerciale_principale';
    $vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['principale'];
  }
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'filtra_principale_cliente_finale' ,2);

/* =======================================
FILTRO COMM. PRINCIPALE - END
======================================= */











/* =======================================
FILTRO COMM. PRINCIPALE STATUS APPROVATO
======================================= */

function list_filter_principale_cliente_finale_approvato(){
  $type = 'cliente_finale';
  if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
    $type = $_GET['post_type'];
  }



  //only add filter to post type you want
  if ('cliente_finale' == $type){
    //change this to the list of values you want to show
    //in 'label' => 'value' format

    $values = array(
      "Da approvare" => "da_approvare",
      "Approvato" => "approvato",
      "Non approvato" => "non_approvato"
    );



    ?>
    <select name="approvato">
      <option value=""><?php _e('Tutti gli status', 'wose45436'); ?></option>
      <?php
      $current_v = isset($_GET['approvato'])? $_GET['approvato']:'';
      foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
        printf
        (
          '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
          $value,
          $value == $current_v? ' selected="selected"':'',
          $label
        );
      }
      ?>
    </select>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'list_filter_principale_cliente_finale_approvato' );


/**
* if submitted filter by post meta
*
* make sure to change META_KEY to the actual meta key
* and POST_TYPE to the name of your custom post type

*/
function filtra_approvato_cliente_finale( $vars ){
  global $pagenow;
  $type = 'cliente_finale';
  if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
    $type = $_GET['post_type'];
  }


  if ( 'cliente_finale' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['approvato']) && $_GET['approvato'] != '') {
    $vars['meta_key'] = 'cliente-finale-approvato_approvato';
    $vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['approvato'];
  }
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'filtra_approvato_cliente_finale',1 );

/* =======================================
FILTRO COMM. PRINCIPALE STATUS APPROVATO - END
======================================= */
```

Here an image of the WordPress custom post-type admin area

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Are you doing with custom code??

Comment: Yes, the custom code you can see above is the one who creates and manage the filters in the admin area